# How do I make an array of undefined classes implementing a specific interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with some properties and functions specifications and some classes that implement this interface. Then I'd like to do an array of arrays containing either of those classes. But when I do this :

```
array: MyInterface[];
```

And then populate it (for exemple with only one class) :

```
array: MyInterface[] = [[new MyClass1(), new MyClass1(), ...], ...];
```

I get an error that MyClass1[] is not MyInterface. How am I supposed to do that sort of sutff ? And if it's impossible in typescript is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do "an array of arrays" then you need to type it with `[][]` instead of `[]`.

```
const arrayToo: MyInterface[][] = [
    [new MyClass1(), new MyClass1()]
]
```

Here it is [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZc5ABygHtKBGALmQGcwpQBzAblIuRgBXEAibIAFAEpkAXgB8yAG41gAE14kAvqVIIANnBYs06AMIGj9ZMAC2lPRBsRwxjNkixEKYmQrU6YmwcIJyyyADkinB6ghD04Rr8QiJWMhLS8oSaGtokujQgbMhwUFBw6MxuOJ5IANoAug1htXwUtSAQAO4m5oYs9FIANMgd3Ri9llL1pPXIpEA).

Comment: I'm ashamed it looked like a type error but the solution was simple.

Comment: That reminds me of once asking a question once about object references that seemed very obvious in hindsight.